# Windows phone panorama title on one page only?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, panorama-control

how can I set the title for the panorama control, to only show on the panoramaitem, without showing over all of them?

Answer (score 2):

You could change the title to an empty string "" when switching the page (there should be events for that) but I can't imagine that will look good and it's against the design guide.
I suggest using pivot view where you can leave the titles of other pivotitems empty.